# Animating covering one div with another div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an effect for a video poker game where one card slides on top of another card.

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15zw3hk8/) is very simple, I think. Here is my code:

CSS:

```
body {
    width:80%;
}

#board {
    width:100%;
    height:25%;
}
div .card {
    width:16%;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}

div .redbox {
  width:100;
  height:100%;
  background-color:red;
}

div .bluebox {
  width:100;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="main">
        <div id="board">
            <div class="card" id="c-0">
                <div class="redbox"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" id="c-1">
                <div class="redbox"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" id="c-2">
                <div class="redbox"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" id="c-3">
                <div class="redbox"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="card" id="c-4">
                <div class="redbox"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button>Click Here!</button>
    </div>
<body>
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var $newDiv = $('<div>');
        $newDiv.addClass('bluebox');
        $newDiv.hide();
        $('#c-' + i).append($newDiv);
        $newDiv.slideToggle();
    }
});
```

My two problems are as follows:

1. I would like to set the width of each card as a percentage and have the height adjust automatically. But if I remove the "height" CSS property, the whole DIV disappears.
2. I cannot figure out how to make one div slide on top of the other one. I do not want to remove the underlying div since it is going to be a generic background image that I always want to be there when there is no card on top.

I think maybe I should also note that in the end I am going to change these div elements to img elements, I just made them colored boxes for simplicity. I don't know if that will make any difference.

**EDITED:**

The first problem is turning out to be the difficult one to correct. By adding "position:relative" to the .card elements and "position:absolute" to the images/colored box div elements, I can get the new one to go on top of the other. But now the containing element has collapsed, and I do not know how to get it to expand to the size of its contents.

New JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yv3mwao9/

Comment: is that for just a game or real gambling?

Comment: just a game, for getting experience with HTML/CSS/JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to your css:

```
#main {
    position: relative;
}
```

change your `bluebox` css

```
div .bluebox {
background-color:blue;
position: absolute;
top:0;
}
```

your jquery:

```
$('button').click(function (e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var $newDiv = $('<div>');
        $newDiv.addClass('bluebox')
               .css({"width": $(".redbox").outerWidth(),
                     "height": $(".redbox").outerHeight()
                   });
        $newDiv.hide();
        $('#c-' + i).append($newDiv);
        $newDiv.slideToggle();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as for the second part, your answer is the z-index css property

(on children of the same element, higher z-index will be printed on top of its siblings)

Note that the position css attribute must be set to relative or absolute for z-index to work

Comment: This solved the second problem, but now the containing div has collapsed (see edit). Any ideas how to expand it?

Comment: My apologies but here you would have to excuse me, as a back-end developer i'm not all that css savvy :)